# Subclassing a CoreData model in a shared library

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, shared-libraries

We just created a shared library (`project-core`) from an existing project (`project-A`) that we are now using in a new project (`project-B`). We moved the xcdatamodeld from `project-A` into project-core and all is fine there. However we want to now create new models in the xcdatamodeld file in `project-B` that extend the models in `project-core`. Everything I've found so far is that you cannot do this in the xcdatamodeld, however people mentioned that you could do it manually in code but no one gave any explanations on how. I have tried subclassing it manually but it didn't work.

What I tried: 
`SharedObject` exists in `project-core`, I created `NewObjectB` in `project-B` with the following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <ProjectCore/ProjectCore.h>

@interface NewObjectB : SharedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;

@end
```

With SharedObject looking like:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface SharedObject : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * description;

@end
```

When I create a NewObjectB object, I can set the name, but it crashes trying to set description due to unrecognized selector so I'm guessing the subclassing isn't working. Is what I'm trying to do even possible and if so, where am I going wrong?

Comment: First, "description" is a terrible name, since it's already used as a method on `NSObject`. Second, is that attribute declared in the managed object model?

Comment: Good point. Sorry, I have simplified these for the example. I'm not actually naming my property "description". But yes, I do have the attributes declared in their respective data models.